# Retrieving the full class path

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs, filepath, eclipse-luna

I am trying to retrieve the full file path from the classes that have been edited. I can retrieve the comments, version number, author and date but can't seem to get the full file path that has been edited when more than one class has been included into the project.

I use these to retrieve the Comments and Author:

```
String comments = pc.getPendingChanges().getComment();
System.out.println("Comments: " + comments);

String author =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getPendingSetOwnerDisplay();
System.out.println("Author: " + author);
```

I use this to retrieve the path:

```
String fileName =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getLocalItem();
System.out.println("FileName: " + fileName);
```

but I only **get** this output:

FileName: C:\VS2013\Plugin\PluginTest\HelloWorld.classpath

I **need** to display the full path with the class name eg

FileName: C:\VS2013\Plugin\PluginTest\HelloWorld.Test.java

Full method displayed below:

```
@Override
public PolicyFailure[] evaluate(PolicyContext context)
            throws PolicyEvaluationCancelledException {

    final PendingCheckin pc =  getPendingCheckin();
    final List<PolicyFailure> failures = new ArrayList<PolicyFailure>();

    final WorkItemCheckinInfo[] AssociatedWorkItems = pc.getWorkItems().getCheckedWorkItems();


    WorkItem AssociatedCodeReview = null;
    String failureReason = "";
    for (int i=0; i<AssociatedWorkItems.length; i++) {
        AssociatedCodeReview = AssociatedWorkItems[i].getWorkItem();
        if (AssociatedCodeReview.getType().getName() == "Code Review") {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (AssociatedCodeReview != null) {
        if (AssociatedCodeReview.getFields().getField("System.State").getValue()
            .toString().equals("Not Approved")) {

            failureReason = "Code Review Work Item associated but that is not approved by expert";
            failures.add(new PolicyFailure(failureReason, this));
        }
    } else {
        String fileName =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getLocalItem();
        System.out.println("FileName: " + fileName);

        String fileName2 =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getServerItem();
        System.out.println("FileName2: " + fileName2);

        String[] fileName3 =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAffectedTeamProjectPaths();
        System.out.println("FileName3: " + fileName3[0]);

        //System.out.println("Found " + pc.getPendingChanges().getAffectedTeamProjectPaths()[0] + " work items.");

        String comments = pc.getPendingChanges().getComment();
        System.out.println("Comments: " + comments);

        String author =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getPendingSetOwnerDisplay();
        System.out.println("Author: " + author);

        String version =  String.valueOf(pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getVersion());
        System.out.println("Version: " + version);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Date Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
    }
    return failures.toArray(new PolicyFailure[failures.size()]);
}
```

Comment: What is pc? What is supposed to be in the starts? What is test.java?

Comment: pc is final PendingCheckin pc =  getPendingCheckin(); and test is just a simple java class for testing that just has a print out statement within it

Comment: What framework is "PendingCheckin" part of?

Comment: import com.microsoft.tfs.core.pendingcheckin.PendingCheckin;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does work, it was an error with my Eclipse install.

```
String fileName =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[x].getLocalItem();
```